# Wordpress goes blank randomly changing plugins folder fixes it

Tags: wordpress

I have a constant issue with my site going blank. Nothing ever shows. To fix it all I have to do is go in with my FTP and rename the plugins folder, refresh the page, and rename the plugins folder back to normal.

How can I have my site up and running at all times? I keep deactivating plugins hoping that it will stop it but after a few hours it goes blank again.

Comment: Open `wp-config.php` and turn on debug to diagnose: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my host and after having them dig around for an hour they finally found the correct log. The problem was the WP-Touch never stopped 'running' so the mobile sites were fine but it would try to take over the desktop and would conflict with our theme. I have since then disabled the plugin and everything seems normal.